# RSpec Testing (Request Specs, Feature Specs & Integration Specs)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, integration-testing

I'm a Ruby on Rails developer and I'm currently learning RSpec. I've gone through basic Rails testing covered in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html that uses Rails built-in testing framework ActiveSupport::TestCase. There I saw Integration testing.

Then when I started learning RSpec and went through the `rspec-rails` documentation on http://rspec.info/documentation/3.3/rspec-rails/, there is talks about Request specs, which many Rails developers prefer using Capybara and FactoryGirl. But Capybara specs are placed under the `spec/features` directory.

So I'm really in a confusion with Request specs, Integration tests and feature specs. What does they do? Are they equivalent? What type of functions are tested in Request/integration/feature specs?

It'll be helpful if someone clears this,

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's important to understand that Rails uses, by default, [minitest](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest).
That being said, you have request specs there too.

RSpec and minitest are just two test frameworks: they provide a set of utilities (natively or through plugins), to help you write tests, so for example the [available assertions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#available-assertions) are provided by minitest and some additions are provided by Rails itself.

So far, from my understanding, integration testing, feature specs and request specs are the same thing. They do have different names/directories, but they can actually be considered an *e2e testing*, which I consider more explicit: **end-to-end testing** means you perform the test like if you are the user, so you open the browser, click a bunch of buttons, fill some fields, press ok, see the result.

That being said, Capybara is considered better for integration testing because it runs on real browser implementations (Selenium is based upon Firefox), so it correctly handles html/javascript/css like modern browsers do, while default Rails implementation lacks behind a bit I believe (I'm not sure about this last sentence, it's been a while since I used it).

[FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) is a completely separate libraries from everything you mentioned, it's just a tool to rapidly instanciate objects with dummy data, helpful in any type of test, even unit tests.

RSpec is a different framework, I use that because when I started, minitest was not a thing (although I'm reconsidering it recently), I like rspec-mocks a lot, so for now I'll stick with it. It's a personal choice though, mostly syntax-based.

**Summary**

So far I came up with a few rules myself for testing: use capybara for integration/feature/request specs (yes, *they are all the same thing*), so you are safe with correct browser parsing.
Use default Rails **request spec** (in Rspec means you mark the test as `type: :request` and put it in `requests` directory) **only** if you are using Rails as a JSON API (so, no real browser interaction), in that case it's much more fast than capybara and already achieve whatever it's required.
Everything else it's unit testing, which is what you'll use mainly (e2e tests can be quite long to write and slow to run), it will allow you to program without F5 driven development (actually, I don't check the browser at all when I develop something for a Rails application, except when I finish code), you should be testing every public method of every class you write, with all possible paths. If you keep every method ~5 lines long, it's easy and fast and your code will improve a lot, not to mention your testing.

Answer (score 1):

> Capybara is no longer supported in
>   request specs as of Capybara 2.0.0. The recommended way to use Capybara is
>   with feature specs.

The above is from the RSpec documentation for 3.3:

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-3/docs/request-specs/request-spec (3.3)

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec (most recent version)

For now:
Use Capybara in your Feature specs.

I think your question is a result of confusion based on reading older articles.  Things have changed.  Read here for more details: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/06/improving-the-integration-between-capybara-and-rspec/